# HARD BRICKED AFTER INSTALLING 4.4.4 UPDATE IN MOTO E 1st gen

Tags: boot, bootloader, reboot

When I updated my mobile, it power offed then it gone to bootloader mode then I pressed on normal power, but it didn't, so I press on recover, it gone to TWRP mode and I pressed on recover, there some codes happened, and then it gone off.  till then nothing working.

not even charging,  and not opening bootloader too.

pls I need your suggestion. THANK YOU

[This video on Youtube](https://youtu.be/enx3KxcWtFU) (published March 2015) is showing same problem that I have. You can see in the comments that still this problem is going on.

see article about Easy JTAG on internet.  you can understand how this begin and end.

Comment: Can you access recovery by holding VOL DN (not VOL DN + PWR) and connecting a USB cable to a PC? I will provide an answer but it isn't likely what you want to hear... this is a known issue that just happens with some Moto's, and not just the E, the G and X have it on occasion as well but it is rare.

Comment: I added my answer... like I said, you probably won't like it but it is an honest one. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are really only 4 viable solutions for a hard bricked Moto "letter" device, assuming this is truly hard bricked and not a battery or charging issue. Being hard bricked on one of these devices means that the bootloader is inaccessible and the device doesn't boot, if the bootloader is inaccessible we have few options remaining for self-repair.

**Qualcomm HS-USB Qloader 9008** - All Qualcomm devices have the ability to be hard flashed *with the proper files*. Although this is an option for many devices, it is not for these devices because Moto/Lenovo will not release the necessary files. Thus this is not a valid option for these devices, I only bring this up because searching the internet will return many references to this tool, but we cannot use it thanks to Moto/Lenovo policy on these devices. - [Source](http://www.androidbrick.com/unbrick-all-qualcomm-snapdragons-from-qualcomm-hs-usb-qdloader-9008-if-you-have-the-right-kind-of-rom-qhsusb_dload_edl/)

**JTAG programming** - Requires an external device and ROM files, assuming the partitioning is still intact this is a viable option although for lower end or older devices, the price of the programmer is often significantly more than the value or replacement cost of the device, with modest units costing around $200USD ([source](http://www.cellcorner.com/xshp/cell-phone-unlocking/jtag-tools/)) without the necessary cables which sometimes need to be purchased separately or fabricated, and the initial cost of this device when new was $100USD and it's current value is around $30USD, most likely makes this option undesirable.

**Authorized Service Center** - Have the device repaired by an authorized Moto service center. Due to the age of this device, it is likely out of warranty and the cost will likely be more than the device's value or replacement cost. I have no reference for this information, so it might be worth your time to investigate it yourself, if this was the result of an official OTA update, it may be possible to find a sympathetic ear at a local authorized repair center.

So this brings us to the **Final Option**... As noted in some of my previous options, the cost/value of the device needs to be considered here. The Moto E is a low-end, low cost device and was released in May 2014, just over 3 years ago. This device has very little value and a replacement unit would likely cost less than any valid repair option, so it may just be time to discard/recycle the device and purchase a new or used replacement device.

Like many things in life, not everything can be feasibly or economically repaired, sometimes you just have to accept that and move on.

Comment: hello, have a nice day, please guide me, that I have gotten device QUALCOMM HS-USB QDLOADER 9008. and then I opened the BLANKFLASH.and showing Massege ( FAILED ‹blank-flash:sdl-transfer-image:sdl-hello:error sending packet› )

Comment: what to do now?

Comment: @BLUENIGHT We do not have the proper files to perform a QDload, the blankflash from the thread linked in the other answer if for the Moto G, it will not work. The thread was closed on XDA because it was WRONG and didn't work. There is no working "unbrick" for the Moto E.

Comment: OK, so mean,  I have to go to service center...... Lastly found the solution 

Answer (score 0):

Rolling back to old os may be difficult. So you can try custom os. But if you need stock rom back try fastboot rom. Check whether fastboot rom is available for you. You may want to use tool to do that

Comment: Sorry, Ankith: But how is this answering the question? OP reports the device "hard bricked", i.e. it doesn't boot in any mode. So there's no way in flashing a ROM or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just something before my answer : *softbrick* is when you still CAN boot into recovery functions of the phone (`fastboot` or `recovery`) or still see some logo appearing on your screen at plug / bootup state ;

While *hardbrick* is when everything went wrong and you destroyed a reserved system / bootloader space that you weren't supposed to touch anyway, so your phone can no longer access anything.

Supposing, from your answer that you are ***hardbricked***, if nothing shows upw
, well... Your phone is pretty much stuck in this state...

It is a good idea to ask a reseller or the manufacturer for a repair; but sometimes this involves a **full** motherboard change because you touched some DRMs or OEM stuff needed for boot.

Comment: I think that there is no other reserved system space except your internal storage.

Comment: There are some OEM partitions, like Sony's TA which is accessible from TWRP, and if you wipe it, your phone is dead forever.

Comment: Your phone internal storage is just like a flash drive. Even if you wipe it completely along with the OEM partition causing it to hardbrick you can reflash it using USB by connecting it with PC. It is just required the right tool.

Comment: defat, can you tell me tools name?  I've tried to connect device to pc but, it's not connecting to the pc,  then I've realise that my mobile was on before that so the battery gone.  then I connected to charger, now it is blinking flash light.  but How to know that my mobile is On or Off?

Comment: @BLUENIGHT  xda has some guides how to flash new ROM in hardbricked phones. I don't know about the tools.

Comment: it says everything depend on hardware devices as EASY JTAG, but I want to flash it by pc without buying any external device. BECAUSE EVERY EXTERNAL DEVICE FOR THIS FUNCTION are  MUCH EXPENSIVE. so help me.

Comment: @defalt internal storage has many partitions. Blank the wrong one, and you can no longer boot. Kill the bootloader, and you can say Goodbye – unless you're able to play with JTAG and its tools (nothing for the "average user").

Comment: @Izzy My friend's phone was completely erased along with the bootloader. It was become a piece of electronics with no software to operate. He still managed to flash new custom ROM into his phone by connecting it with PC. He did use some tool to flash it. How manufacturers install their stock ROM when manufacturing of the phone hardware is completed?

Comment: @defalt depends on the hardware. First, they of course have the means (correct JTAG setup), second they probably just through it away and send you a replacement. Third, it makes a difference whether you've got an MTK (which seems to have a kind of "read only emergency boot loader" so Flashtool can connect it even if "hard bricked" – though there's also some "partition" you shouldn't touch), or something not having such a special setup.